# Ordenar tabela por nome

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma tabela, que mostra todos os dados da base de dados SQLite. Queria ordenar por nome todos os dados e apresentá-los. Tenho um hyperlink que chama uma função para ordenar. O problema é que não funciona. Como posso fazer para apresentar na tabela, na mesma página.

```
$base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);
$requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY id desc";   
$resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    // 
$affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();// 
$nombreid = $affiche['id'];

function order($base, $dir,$lib_module,$nombreid){

    for($i=1;$i<=$nombreid;$i++)
    {       
        $base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);
        $requete    =   "SELECT prenom FROM $lib_module ORDER BY prenom ASC ";  
        $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    // 
        $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();// 

        echo $affiche['prenom'];
    }
}   

if (isset($_GET['ordername'])) {
    order($base,$dir,$lib_module,$nombreid);
}
```

E aqui a tabela, ordenada por ID.

```
echo "<table border=0>\n";      
    echo "<tr align=center>\n";


    echo "<td>ID</td>\n";
    echo "<td><a href=?ordername=true>Nome</a></td>\n";
    echo "<td>Ultimo Nome</td>\n";
    echo "<td></td>\n";

for($i=1;$i<=$nombreid;$i++)
    {       
        $requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i)";  
        $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    // 
        $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();//  tableau 'affiche'

        if($affiche['id']!=0)
        {
            //write data 
            echo "<tr class=event bgcolor=$couleur align=left style='font-size:12px;font-family:helvetica'>\n";

            echo "<td title=\"$lib_id\"><a href=_compil_vcf.php?id=$affiche[id]>$affiche[id]</a></td>\n";
            echo "<td >$affiche[nom]</td>\n";
            echo "<td >$affiche[prenom]</td>\n";
            echo "<td >$affiche[fonction]</td>\n";
        title=\"$clic_for_mail\" >$affiche[mail]</a></td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n"; 
        }

    }//fin de for               
    echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: quais erros o php retorna ?

Comment: Não me orderna por nome, tenho bem a função order a ordenar por ASC, e qd clico no hyperlink chama a função. Quero que altera a tabela em baixo

Comment: certo, erro ao copiar.

Comment: @akm, deixa eu ver se entendi. Você tem uma tabela já populada, e, ao clicar em um link, quer que essa tabela seja ordenada. Confere?

Comment: Exatamente, quero por ordem de nome, e depois pelos outros campos da tabela.

Answer (score 1):

> ## TL;DR
>
> Você precisa repensar sua implementação. Não é possível "reordenar" dados já enviados ao cliente do lado do servidor. Busque se informar sobre Ajax e soluções do lado cliente.

Essa é uma confusão muito comum. É importante entender o que acontece no lado do cliente e no lado do servidor quando você clica no link de "ordenação".

Grosseiramente, quanto você clica em um link uma nova requisição http é efetuada pelo navegador. Essa requisição é recebida pelo seu servidor http, que identifica que aquela chamada deve ser tratada por um interpretador PHP. O seu servidor http faz então o que é necessário (e.g., através de um módulo do Apache): Chama o interpretador PHP e responde a chamada http com o conteúdo gerado pelo seu código (e.g., com *markup* HTML gerado pelo PHP). O seu navegador então exibe esse novo resultado, descartando o que estava na tela anteriormente.

Nesse fluxo "padrão" não há como o PHP manipular nada que já foi entregue ao cliente (no seu caso, ordenar dados de uma tabela). Não há nenhuma relação entre a variável `$affiche` da segunda requisição e o corpo da tabela que foi gerado na primeira requisição (mesmo que você tenha utilizado a variável `$affiche` na primeira requisição para construir a tabela).

## Então quais são as minhas opções?

1. Devolver uma página completa com os dados da tabela reordenados: O PHP vai gerar todo o markup html novamente, não apenas os dados ou o corpo da tabela.
2. Usar uma `iframe` para a tabela (não faça isso).
3. Ordenar os dados no próprio cliente. Você pode fazer isso com JavaScript.
4. Construir um fluxo Ajax em que:

   1. O navegador envia uma requisição em *background* (sem descartar a página atual).
   2. O servidor responde com os dados ordenados em alguma notação (json, xml, yaml, etc)
   3. O navegador recebe essa resposta e chama uma função JavaScript de *callback*, responsável por "descartar" os dados na tabela atual e exibir os dados retornados pelo servidor.

Devolver uma nova página completa é uma opção comum (ainda que "desperdice" um pouco de banda, pode ser mais viável em alguns casos). Ordenar dados no próprio cliente é uma opção viável para quantidades pequenas de dados não paginados. Ajax é a solução mais moderna; apesar de envolver vários componentes (cliente, servidor, formato de transmissão de dados, *callbacks* assíncronos, etc), não é tão complexo quanto aparenta.

Comment: Too didn't; didn't read?

Comment: Too didn't, didn't didn't; Fixed!

Comment: Como posso ordenar os dados em JavaScript?

Comment: Se quiser fazer "na unha" de uma olhada nesse post do [SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558182/sort-a-table-fast-by-its-first-column-with-javascript-or-jquery). Eu recomendaria uma biblioteca especializada como o [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) ou [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/demo/php/jqgrid/)